# How to convert the following into array or hash?

Tags: ruby

```
a=b&c=d&e=f&g=h
```

How to extract this into `[a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h]`

I know I can use split, but it looks like it can only use only one delimit.

or how to convert into a hash?

Comment: Are you doing this through some sort of web request? As in, are those query parameters?

Comment: No, it is not query strings, it is response from some web post

Answer (score 5):

split FTW (i.e. the most straightforward, simple way of doing this is):

```
irb(main):001:0> s = "a=b&c=d&e=f&g=h"
=> "a=b&c=d&e=f&g=h"
irb(main):002:0> s.split(/[=&]/)
=> ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"]
```

Other interesting ways of abusing Ruby:

```
irb(main):001:0> s = "a=b&c=d&e=f&g=h"
=> "a=b&c=d&e=f&g=h"
irb(main):002:0> s.split('=').collect{|x| x.split('&')}.flatten
=> ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"]
irb(main):003:0> ['=','&'].inject(s) {|t, n| t.split(n).join()}.split('')
=> ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"]
```

Also check Cary's and GamesBrainiac's answers for more alternatives :)

Comment: Thanks for this! I'm a little rusty on ruby, and I didn't know you could do that.

Comment: You could replace `collect` and `flatten` with `flat_collect`, er, I mean [Enumerable#flat_map](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-flat_map).

Answer (score 1):

You can make a hash very easily with something like this:

```
myHash  = {} 
strSplit = "a=b&c=d&e=f&g=h".split("&")
for pair in strSplit
   keyValueSplit = pair.split("=")
   myHash[keyValueSplit[0]] = keyValueSplit[1]
end
```

`myHash` will look like this in the end `{"a"=>"b", "c"=>"d", "e"=>"f", "g"=>"h"}`

Answer (score 1):

@Mirea's answer is best, but here's another:

```
s = "a=b&c=d&e=f&g=h"

s.scan /[a-z]/
  #=> ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"]
```

The regex could of course be adjusted as required. For example:

```
"123a=b&c=d&E=f&g=h".scan /[A-Za-z0-9]/
  #=> ["1", "2", "3", "a", "b", "c", "d", "E", "f", "g", "h"]
```

or

```
"1-2-3a=$b&c=d&e=f&g=h".scan /[^=&]/
  #=> ["1", "-", "2", "-", "3", "a", "$", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"]
```

and so on.

If strings of characters are desired just append `+` to the character class:

```
"123a=b&ccc=d&E=f&gg=h".scan /[A-Za-z0-9]+/
  #=> ["123a", "b", "ccc", "d", "E", "f", "gg", "h"]
```

If the string has the alternating form shown in the example, these work as well:

```
(0..s.size).step(2).map { |i| s[i] }
  #=> ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"]

s.each_char.each_slice(2).map(&:first)
  #=> ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"]
```

Comment: thanks :) small nitpick on your answer: it relies on the structure of the input string. for example: test=1023&nottest=99a will not work

Comment: @Mircea, I assumed that was a given, but you have a good point. Will adjust my answer.

Comment: here is 2 alternative ways: 1) s.split('=').collect{|x| x.split('&')}.flatten 2) ['=','&'].inject(s) {|t, n| t.split(n).join()}.split('')

Answer (score 0):

I would use is `gsub`.

```
irb(main):001:0> s = "a=b&c=d&e=f&g=h"
=> "a=b&c=d&e=f&g=h"
irb(main):004:0> s.gsub(/[\=\&]/, " ").split()
=> ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"]
```

So, what we're doing here is replacing all occurrences of `=` and `&` with a single space. We then simply `split` the string.